# Cannot modify a primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I want to change kd_absen's length from 10 to 20 in the table called "absen". It's a primary key though.

And what happened next, phpmyadmin gave me this error massage

https://s.kaskus.id/r320x320/images/2017/07/08/9793710_20170708101310.JPG

What I tried so far: I tried to temporarily deleting the `kd_absen` in "penggajian" table (and re create it later). But a similar message appeared.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to change the field in both table

Comment: @colour dalnet

Ive tried to change the length of the one on penggajian table. And it gave me similar massage

Comment: You have to remove the foreign key first. The reference of a foreign key has to have the same datatype. Either if you are trying to change the referenced or the reference column first, the types won't match since the other column ist still unchanged. So remove the foreign key, change both columns (to the exact same type) and recreate the foreign key again.

Comment: @solarflare.

Sorry, the problem is already solved. I removed the constraint via relation.

And, no, your suggestion doesnt work. Ive tried that before. Removing the foreign key doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Remove the constraint of the primary key
2 - Alter the primary key field length
3 - Create another constraint to the primary key